# Windows 7 Gadgets - Windows 7 Logo Program Certification

Tags: windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

One of the requirements for the "Windows 7 Logo Program" is that the application must be a standalone application. **Does a Windows 7 gadget qualify as a standalone application?**

To my knowledge, a gadget runs under the Sidebar.exe process (also in Windows 7). Though the Sidebar is not visible in Windows 7 it runs in the background when a gadget is run.

Answer (score 0):

The best people to ask would be Microsoft (maybe on the MSDN forums?).  Saying that a gadget runs under sidebar.exe so it does not count as standalone would be much like saying that a VB.NET program isn't standalone because it requires .NET but there are .net applications out there with the "Windows 7 logo program" badges.

Comment: Well, Running under a process is different from requiring something to run. Sidebar.exe runs all the gadgets in its process whereas .NET applications runs in their own processes. I have raised a question for the MSDN guys... and will post the response when I get from them.

Comment: True and I suppose that's a good point.  They do load libraries from the CLR, though.  I have never seen a gadget with the Windows 7 logo, though but yours might be the first.